# Database turned to 'default' when authentication is correct

Tags: mongodb, symfony

This is my config :

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: 'mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019'
            options:
                username: sshuichi
                password: complexpassword
                db: mydb
```

When the password is not correct , I have this error :

> Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on
>   database 'mydb' with username 'sshuichi': auth failed; Failed to
>   connect to: localhost:27018: Authentication failed on database 'mydb'
>   with username 'sshuichi': auth failed; Failed to connect to:
>   localhost:27019: Authentication failed on database 'mydb' with
>   username 'sshuichi': auth failed

Please notice it's talking about `mydb`

When the password is correct, I have

> not authorized on default to execute command

Why on earth is it talking about default this time ?

Comment: Don't know about doctrine, but there is a `authDB`. In which database have you created the user?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky That's just the id of the connection, my database is mydb

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg in 'mydb' database.